# How do I filter a search result by category using dropdown options from API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had to implement two main functionalities:

- One is getting data from an API and then filtering it through a search bar which I've done - regarding this, can I pass a setState as a prop from one component to another? The search bar is working when I put it in the same component but doesn't even if I pass it as a callback function in the parent component.
- Secondly and most importantly, I need to put two dropdown options (Country and Vehicle in this case) and filter the search data if it matches the option selected from the dropdown.

Here is the sandbox [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-chaum-g46g2v?file=/src/Dropdown.js)

Thanks.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code here instead of giving a link. This is because code on other sites can change over time. See this [FAQ for more detail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/17493431)

Answer (score 1):

Few things that need changing in your app.

You are managing your data state inside the Dropdown component, but this data state needs to be shared between the **Dropdown**, and the **Search** components, so is best to have it at the root of them, in this case **App**.

You can then pass the state to the **App** child components, **Dropdown**, and **Search**.

I only focused on the **Dropdown** component, and the implementation I will show you can be improved, but it will be easy to follow and it will give you a good starting point in my opinion, if not feel free to ask.

**App.js**

I have move the logic to fetch the data and the state here, and then we pass it to the Dropdown component as props.

You can do the same for the **Search** component, by creating a search term state for example.

There is an extra `useEffect` that will take care of updating the `filteredData` state based on the `selectedCountry` and `selectedVehicle` state values.

```
import "./styles.css";
import Search from "./Search";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState("");
  const [selectedVehicle, setSelectedVehicle] = useState("");

  // ========== FETCHING API DATA ==========
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://612619c7e40e1900170727fe.mockapi.io/api/users"
      );
      setData(res.data);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // If the state changes filter the results
    // Quick and dirty filter, you can improve on this
    if (selectedCountry || selectedVehicle) {
      const found = data.filter(
        (item) =>
          item.country === selectedCountry || item.vehicle === selectedVehicle
      );
      setFilteredData(found);
    } else {
      setFilteredData(data);
    }
  }, [data, selectedCountry, selectedVehicle]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="top-section">
        <h1 className="top-title">Filter:</h1>
        {/* Pass the state as props to this child component */}
        <Dropdown
          data={data}
          setSelectedCountry={setSelectedCountry}
          setSelectedVehicle={setSelectedVehicle}
        />

        <div className="user-search">
          <Search data={data} />

          {/* Render the filtered data */}
          {filteredData.map((item) => (
            <div className="user-profile" key={item.id}>
              <img
                src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1378/PNG/512/avatardefault_92824.png"
                className="pfp"
                alt="user-avatar"
              />
              <p style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{item.name}</p>
              <p style={{ opacity: "0.8" }}>{item.email}</p>
              <p>{item.country}</p>
              <p>{item.vehicle}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Dropdown.js**

This component takes `data`, `selectedCountry` and `selectedVehicle` App state as props, and set the values when an option is selected.

```
// Get the App state as props
function Dropdown({ data, setSelectedCountry, setSelectedVehicle }) {
  // FUNCTION TO RESET SEARCH RESULT
  function reset() {
    // Reset the state values
    setSelectedCountry("");
    setSelectedVehicle("");
  }

  // MAIN JSX
  return (
    <div className="dropdown">
      {/* LOADING DROPDOWN OPTIONS */}
      <div className="dropdown-options">
        <select
          className="dd-item"
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedCountry(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option value="">Country</option>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <option key={item.id} value={item.country}>
              {item.country}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>

        <select
          className="dd-item"
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedVehicle(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option value="">Vehicle</option>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <option key={item.id} value={item.vehicle}>
              {item.vehicle}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>

        <button className="reset" onClick={reset}>
          RESET
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

**Search.js**

I didn't change much here, other than displaying the cards in the App component.

You don't need to fetch the data again, and pass it as a prop, like I did to the **Dropdown** component, but I'll leave it up to you to clean it up.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

function Search() {
  const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [output, setOutput] = useState([]);

  // =============== GETTING API DATA ===============

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://612619c7e40e1900170727fe.mockapi.io/api/users"
      );
      setSearchData(res.data);
      setOutput(res.data);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  // ========== MATCHING SEARCH INPUT WITH API DATA ==========

  useEffect(() => {
    setOutput([]);
    searchData.filter((item) => {
      if (
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()) ||
        item.country.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()) ||
        item.email.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()) ||
        item.vehicle.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        setOutput((output) => [...output, item]);
      }
    });
  }, [input]);

  function searchInput(e) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <input
      className="searchbar"
      type="text"
      placeholder="SEARCH"
      onChange={searchInput}
    ></input>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried to get filteredData to Search.js and map it but it says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')".  I've updated the code from the post.

Comment: @codebyday If you don't mind please accept the answer and create a new post with you new question as it will help other people searching for the same issue, that is the core of Stackoverflow. Ping me to the new question and I'll give a hand. I'll gladly go over a private chat if so you wish.

Comment: @codebyday  Also it will be best to add the code to the question instead of a link, again other users may have the same/similar problem and it will be great to have a reference instead of a potential dead link.